# Wordpress reverse date format for display but not db

Tags: wordpress, date, posts

I have a events page using a custom wp_query so that I can split post into upcoming events and past events. To do this I need the date to be stored in the database Y/m/d format but would like it to display on the front ends d/m/y. Any help on how I should do this, I could reverse it with jquery but there might be a better way?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is probably using [the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) function.

If so, modify it using format parameter to something like this:

```
the_date('d/m/Y');
```

Check also [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) Codex page about formatting the date and time.